# Calling function with entry value returns with frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have the below code, actualy two functions within aframe itself. So I am calling the second function with the value of an entry..

Now the called function receives the value as a tuple, with first value as:
<**main**.StartPage object .!frame.!startpage>

Need help to fix it.

```
def loadFile(self):
    self.filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("info", "*.xlsx"), ("all file", "*.*")))
    if self.filename:
        extension = self.filename[self.filename.rfind('.'):]
        if extension == '.ods':
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error message")
        else:
            vVerify = self.verifyExcel(self.filename)
            if vVerify == 1:
                self.verify_button = tk.Button(self, text="Verified")
                self.verify_button.grid(row=1,column=2)
                #self.filename = self.filename.split("/")[-1]
                self.filedir.delete(0, "end")
                #self.filedir.insert(0, self.dirName+self.filename)
                self.filedir.insert(0, self.filename)
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error message 1")

def verifyExcel(*xlFile):
    print(xlFile)
```

I'm just using xlFile[1] to get the actual value but it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
vVerify = self.verifyExcel(self.filename)
```

this is syntactic sugar for

```
vVerify = YourClass.verifyExcel(self, self.filename)
```

Thus, with the method being declared as `def verifyExcel(*xlFile)`, the `xlFile` parameter will be the tuple `(self, self.filename)`. The canonical way would be to declare the method with two parameters, the first being `self`, even if you don't need the `self` parameter:

```
def verifyExcel(self, xlFile):
    print(xlFile)
```

Comment: @BinayakChatterjee Then please be more specific what "the problem" is. This way, you do not have to do `xlFile[1]` but `xlFile` itself is the value that you need.

Comment: changed it to vVerify = self.verifyExcel(self, self.filename)

Still print(xlFIle) prints this:
('D:/Project/Noida-3/ExcelDemoForAudit - Copy.xlsx',)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Comment: @BinayakChatterjee No, you call it the same as you did before. The `self` is implicitly added as the first parameter. Now you are passing `(self, self, self.filename)`

Comment: Got it. I'm new to it. Thanks for helping me out.